# responding to (500) internal server error

Tags: powershell

how do I react to a 500 Internal Server Error?
Lets say that I have the code below:

```
$webpage = $webclient.DownloadString("http://moocow/Addfoo.asmx/roflmao?inputFoofoo=$variable")
```

In my case I have a page that returns some information; however, occassionally the page goes down and returns a 500 Internal server error.  how do I tell the script to preform another action if that is the case?
The following is the error I get:

```
Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."
At \\ASERVER\AFOLDER\ASCRIPT.ps1:112 char:57
+                 $global:webpage = $webclient.DownloadString <<<< ("http://moocow/Addfoo.asmx/roflmao?inputFoofoo=$variable")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a try/catch block:

```
$webPage = $null

try
{
  $webPage = $webClient.DownloadString(...)
}
catch
{
  "Error getting webpage!"
}

if($webPage)
{
   "Getting the webpage worked!"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

talking for php, you may think similar..
$webpage will probably return false, if the host is down.

you may perform you operation like this:

```
if($webpage)
{
   perform operations
}
else
{
   exceptional case
}
```